# Composing lenses with Control.Lens where an intermediate function must be called

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lenses

Suppose I have the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data Book = Book {
  _author :: String,
  _title :: String
} deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Book

data Location = Location {
  _city :: String,
  _state :: String
} deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Location

data Library = Library {
  _location :: Location,
  _books :: [Book]
} deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Library

lib :: Library
lib = Library (Location "Baltimore" "MD") [Book "Plato" "Republic", Book "Aristotle" "Ethics"]
```

I'm trying to understand various ways of reaching down through multiple layers by composing lenses. I know how to do these operations:

```
-- returns "Baltimore"
lib ^. location . city

-- returns a copy of lib with the city replaced
set (location . city) "Silver Spring" lib
```

But what if I want to change book titles? Maybe I want to change them all using `map`, or I just want to change the third one using `!! 2`? It seems I should make a new lens for that. I think I should compose the `books` and `title` lenses with an intermediate function, namely `map` or `!!`.

```
books . (!! 2) . title
-- or
books . map . title
```

How would I go about that?

Comment: if I'm understanding the question properly, read up on maps and traversals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

muhmuhten is correct you should read about [traversals](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.9.0.3/doc/html/Control-Lens-Traversal.html) in the [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package.

```
> over (books . traverse . title) (++" hi") lib
Library {_location = Location {_city = "Baltimore", _state = "MD"}, _books = [Book {_author = "Plato", _title = "Republic hi"},Book {_author = "Aristotle", _title = "Ethics hi"}]}
```

`traverse` allows you to deal with every element in a list.  If you want to effect one element of a list then you use `element` which takes an `Int` to indicate the index dealt with.

```
> over (books . element 0 . title) (++" hi") lib
Library {_location = Location {_city = "Baltimore", _state = "MD"}, _books = [Book {_author = "Plato", _title = "Republic hi"},Book {_author = "Aristotle", _title = "Ethics"}]}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! What if it hadn't been a list? I.e. what if it was an arbitrary data type, and I needed some arbitrary function to access an inner record?

Comment: If it was an arbitrary record then you would use the record lens as normal. I think however you mean other recursive data structure. ex what if it was a tree rather then a list? With that in mind traverse is not just for lists it is for any data type that has a traversable instance. Read about traversables in the [`Data.Traversable` module in base] (http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.1/doc/html/Data-Traversable.html). If you had a custom data type you would write a traversable instance and use the `traverse` like I did for the list above.

Comment: Thanks! That (writing a Traversable instance) was exactly what I was looking for.